# acpi_listen: can't open socket /var/run/acpid.socket: No such file or directory

Tags: acpi

I need to use the **acpi_listen** command. It wasn't installed so I did:

```
pacman -S acpid
```

Then when I run the command **acpi_listen** I get:

```
acpi_listen: can't open socket /var/run/acpid.socket: No such file or directory
```

I checked the in `/var/run` and the file does not exist. If I do a **ps -ef | grep acpi**, it outputs:

```
[acpi_thermal_pm]
[ktpacpid]
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 12):

In archlinux, this will make it work: `systemctl start acpid.service`

Comment: This should be marked as accepted! :)

Comment: It does not make it work. At least a hint to status and error message should be given to debug the situation or at least give it up

Comment: That's the `systemd` way, so ArchLinux is "Poetterized" as well?

Answer (score 0):

For me the acpid.service was already running. I use Debian 9 (stretch) so this might not be the case for everybody.

`/var/run/acpid.socket` is the default location. Checking the systemd status of `acpid.socket` reveals where the actual socket file being used is located.

```
$ systemctl status acpid.socket 
● acpid.socket - ACPID Listen Socket
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/acpid.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-03-25 18:33:04 CET; 41min ago
   Listen: /run/acpid.socket (Stream)
```

Just create a symlink to the default socket location and you're good to go:

```
sudo ln -s /run/acpid.socket /var/run/acpid.socket
```

Alternatively, specify which socket you want to use:

```
acpi_listen -s /run/acpid.socket
```